# Why Args initialized before function init?

Tags: go

`src/os/proc.go`:

```
// Args hold the command-line arguments, starting with the program name.
var Args []string

func init() {
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        // Initialized in exec_windows.go.
        return
    }
    Args = runtime_args()
}
```

When i debugged here,i found Args initialized before init function. Where does it initialied?

Answer (score 1):

As the comment states: `// Initialized in exec_windows.go.`

`src/os/exec_windows.go`:

```
func init() {
    p := syscall.GetCommandLine()
    cmd := syscall.UTF16ToString((*[0xffff]uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(p))[:])
    if len(cmd) == 0 {
        arg0, _ := Executable()
        Args = []string{arg0}
    } else {
        Args = commandLineToArgv(cmd)
    }
}
```